# Even and odd components of a constant function

Tags: signal-analysis, self-study

Let $x(t)= 1$ for all values of $t$. The even and odd components of $x(t)$ are ____ , _____
respectively.

Comment: This looks like homework with effort on your own

Comment: there are straight-forward expressions for the even and odd components.

Answer (score 2):

You may ask yourself first whether the function is already even or odd. If not, check whether it contains an obvious odd/even part, and then whether the remainder is itself even/odd.

Finally, you can use the hammer of the parity decomposition. A function $f(t) $ can be split into the even and odd parts:

$$f(t) =\frac{1} {2} \big[f(t)+f(-t)\big]+ \frac{1} {2} \big[f(t)-f(-t)\big] $$

but it is often better to look at the function first.